# SocketAsyncEventArgs? - simple example

Tags: c#, sockets, xna, multiplayer, socketasynceventargs

As the progress of my XNA TopDown Shooter game continues, it's time to implement multiplayer functionality.
Because the client and server will have to handle alot of data per second (60 packets per second with position, rotation and other player data) I have to make a stable and fast network system.

My question:
What is the best option to create a very fast, high performance network connection between 1 server and multiple clients?
If the answer is SocketAsyncEventArgs, do you know a simple, clean example somewhere on the internet of how to send and receive data using this advanced class? I can't seem to find a nice example that I understand.

Thanks for your time!

Bas

Comment: Here is a [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod).

Comment: I have seen that one already, but I asked for a simple and clean example, not a super high tech example with all the classes etc ;)

Answer (score 0):

here's a blog about it

http://socketeering.blogspot.com/

couple youtube videos in the links

Comment: The link is now broken in 2016. Any idea if it moved somewhere?